# I am using google line chart but unable to provide padding at origin to start graph at some distance away from it

Tags: charts, linechart

I have to create one graph which starts at some distance from the origin. And in that graph one small vertical line shows for every value of x-axis and y-axis. I don't have to show gridlines which I'm able to hide. In the graph I have to show main line of X-axis and Y-axis. If no data is available in response for a graph. No graph will be drawn and also legend related to that graph will be hidden.

I tried these codes:

```
const options = {
        chartArea: {
          bottom: 50, // Add space at the bottom
          left: 50,
          right: 200,
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: "Time",
          
         
          textPosition: "out",
          gridlines: { color: "#000", count: 8 },
          // baseline: 50,
          ticks: [
            "09:40",
            "09:41",
            "09:42",
            "09:43",
            "09:44",
            "09:45",
            "09:46",
            "09:47",
          ],
        },
        vAxis: {
          ticks: [0, 50, 100, 150, 200],
          baseline: -10,
          viewWindowMode: "explicit",
          viewWindow: { min: -10, max: 200 },
          gridlines: { color: "#fff", count: 0 },
          textStyle: { color: "#333", fontSize: 12 },
        },
        legend: "true",
      };
```

[expected chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYJZf.png)
[actual chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH9SI.png)